# C# Sorting on multiple values without knowing types beforehand

Tags: c#

The following code sorts by object.ToString() and thus what I thought was working, was not.

My question is whether there's a way to accomplish the goal of sorting a list of multi-value rows (of unknown column type).

I only need to support int, double, string, DateTime, and TimeSpan. Sorting is always Ascending.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable("TableFu") 
{ Columns = { "Name", "Age", "Grade", "BirthDay", "HowLong" } };

table.Rows.Add("Abe", 2, 1.3, new DateTime(2016, 1, 13), new TimeSpan(0, 30, 30));
table.Rows.Add("Abe", 1, 2.3, new DateTime(2016, 10, 13), new TimeSpan(1, 30, 30));
table.Rows.Add("Abe", 1, 2.3, new DateTime(2016, 2, 13), new TimeSpan(1, 30, 30));
table.Rows.Add("Abe", 1, 1.3, new DateTime(2016, 1, 13), new TimeSpan(1, 30, 30));
table.Rows.Add("Abe", 10, 1.3, new DateTime(2016, 1, 13), new TimeSpan(2, 30, 30));
table.Rows.Add("Abe", 1, 1.3, new DateTime(2016, 1, 13), new TimeSpan(1, 35, 30));
table.Rows.Add("Betty", 1, 2.3, new DateTime(2016, 1, 13), new TimeSpan(1, 30, 30));
table.Rows.Add("Betty", 1, 2.4, new DateTime(2014, 1, 13), new TimeSpan(1, 30, 30));
table.Rows.Add("Betty", 1, 10.4, new DateTime(2015, 1, 13), new TimeSpan(1, 30, 30));

using (DataView view = new DataView(table)) {
    view.Sort = "Name,Age,Grade,BirthDay,HowLong";
    DataTable result = view.ToTable();  //sorted by those columns in Ascending order
}
```

[image]

Per @InBetween and @PeterDuniho, here's what I came up with.

```
class ListComparer : IComparer<List<object>> {
    int IComparer<List<object>>.Compare(List<object> x, List<object> y) {
        return CompareList(x, y);
    }

    private int CompareList(List<object> first, List<object> other) {
        for (int i = 0; i < first.Count; ++i) {
            var firstitem = first[i] as IComparable;
            var otheritem = other[i] as IComparable;
            if (firstitem == null)
                throw new Exception("first item does not implement IComparable");
            if (otheritem == null)
                throw new Exception("other item does not implement IComparable");
            if (firstitem.CompareTo(otheritem) != 0) {
                return firstitem.CompareTo(otheritem);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args) {

    if (1 as IComparable != null) Console.WriteLine("integer is IComparable");
    if (2.3 as IComparable != null) Console.WriteLine("double is IComparable");
    if ("a string" as IComparable != null) Console.WriteLine("string is IComparable");
    if (new DateTime(2016, 10, 30) as IComparable != null) Console.WriteLine("DateTime is IComparable");
    if (new TimeSpan(10, 23, 16) as IComparable != null) Console.WriteLine("TimeSpan is IComparable");

    List<List<Object>> list = new List<List<object>>();
    list.Add(new List<object>() { 2, 3.5, new DateTime(2016, 10, 10) });
    list.Add(new List<object>() { 1, 3.5, new DateTime(2016, 1, 1) });
    list.Add(new List<object>() { 10, 3.5, new DateTime(2016, 1, 1) });
    list.Add(new List<object>() { 2, 10.5, new DateTime(2016, 1, 1) });
    list.Add(new List<object>() { 1, 3.6, new DateTime(2016, 1, 1) });
    list.Add(new List<object>() { 10, 3.4, new DateTime(2016, 1, 1) });
    list.Add(new List<object>() { 2, 3.5, new DateTime(2016, 3, 10) });
    list.Add(new List<object>() { 1, 3.5, new DateTime(2016, 1, 1) });
    list.Add(new List<object>() { 10, 3.5, new DateTime(2016, 1, 1) });

    Console.WriteLine("\nUnsorted list of objects\n");
    foreach (var sublist in list) {
        foreach (var item in sublist) {
            Console.Write(item + "\t\t");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    list.Sort(new ListComparer());

    Console.WriteLine("\nSorted list of objects\n");

    foreach (var sublist in list) {
        foreach (var item in sublist) {
            Console.Write(item + "\t\t");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }


    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Would it not be easier to have this as a function and only add one add and call the function to add and sort as it is called. or simply reorder the data to be in the correct order.

Comment: @Shon: But how do you order/reorder if you don't know the types ahead of time? In a simpler way different from above?

Comment: you are just changing the order of the columns, it's still the same type being sorted.

Comment: @muratgu: notice my second set of add rows? The names of the columns are the same, but the data in the columns is quite different. Yet sorting works (i.e. the 1's before the 2's)

Comment: it is working because the data is being converted to valid values. Also you could use list but it would be more complicated and harder to manage. I believe datatables are your best bets

Comment: if you are claiming that the sorted results are the same, I don't think that's correct. second one will sort by age.

Comment: @muratgu: yes, exactly. The second one sorts in a different order. So how can I do the same thing without using System.Data? :)

Comment: what do you mean `exactly`? the second sort result is wrong.

Comment: @muratgu: I added screenshots to illustrate. The second sorting is sorting differently from the first and that is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @muratgu: The example above works perfectly and meets my requirements. I'm looking for a _different_ way to do the same thing that does not involve DataTables/DataViews.

Comment: .NET has a number of options for ordering data. You can wrap data in classes that implement `IComparable<T>`, you can use a method that takes a `Comparison<T>` delegate, or you can use a method that takes an `IComparer<T>` implementation. In each case, you would have to assume that the unknown types themselves implement `IComparable`, and delegate your own comparison to that implementation.

Comment: As stated, this question is far too broad. You really need to research the existing data ordering mechanisms in .NET first, so that you can ask a more specific question in which you've included a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you've already tried, along with a precise description of what _specifically_ you need help with.

Comment: Your question is "is it possible to do this without DataTable?" The author of the DataTable class managed to do it without DataTable, so *yes*.  How?  Read the source code and you'll know.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: that's becoming clear :) I've already researched other ways, but the dynamic nature of the typing seems to be a blocker.

Comment: @EricLippert: I can see how my question isn't well proposed, but I can't imagine a more condescending or unhelpful response. So thanks for that. How you got up-votes is baffling to me.

Comment: No condescending was intended, and it is intended to be helpful. The answer to your question is in the source code. Read it! That will be far more likely to solve your problem than any of the suggestions made in the comments. (Aside of course from the comment suggesting that you do some research and ask a better question.)

Comment: Or, if you can't find the source code, *decompile the library* and look at the decompiled code. Either way, if you want to know how something works, take it apart and examine it carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordering you are seeing is not the ordering that you think is happening. The view is not sorting by the *actual* type of the object, its simply ordering by the *string representation* of the object, that is, what `object.ToString()` returns.

An easy way to see this is simply adding in your second example a row with Name `10`. The ordering you will get is not numerical `1`, `1`, ... , `2`, `2`, ... , `10`. What you'll get is `1`, `1`, ... , `10`, `2`, ...

So this is probably not what you want.

As a pointer to posible solutions, the way `Enumerable.OrderBy` works for example is that for any `Enumerable<T>` it checks if the type implements `IComparable<T>` or `IComparable` (in that order) and uses the corresponding `CompareTo` implementation.

Its interesting to note that in case of an `IEnumerable<object>` it will only check for the non generic `IComparable`. The following will not work:

```
class MyComparable: IComparable<MyComparable> { ... }
var objectList = new List<object>() { myComparable1, myComparable2, ... };
var ordered = objectList.OrderBy(o => o); //Throws, MyComparable does not impement `IComparable`
```

The reason of this behavior is that there is no easy or reasonably performant way of figuring out if an object with unknown type implements `IComparable<himself>` and then leveraging that information:

```
 var t = o.GetType();
 var genericIComparableOfItself = t.GetInterfaces()
                                   .Where(i => i.IsGenericType && 
                                               i.GetGenericTypeDefinition().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IComparable<>)) &&
                                               i.GetGenericArguments().First() == t)
                                   .FirstOrDefault();

 Func<object, int> compareTo = other => (int)comp.GetMethod("CompareTo", new Type[] { t }).Invoke(o, new object[] { other }); //yuck!
```

This is one reason why it is always a good idea to implement `IComparable` when implementing `IComparable<T>`.

Comment: So if I were to implement wrapper types that implement IComparable, I could make this work? I'll give that a try. Thanks for pointing out how my example is not working as I thought.

Comment: @Rake36 Well, first check if the expected types implement `IComparable`, that is easy to do: `o is IComparable;`. If it doesn't then one option is wrapping the types yes. Another is creating a `IComparer` factory and supplying the appropiate one to `Sort`.

Comment: @Rake36 `public static IComparer GetComparer(Typte t)` and you could even cache them with a `IDictionary<Type, IComparer>`.

Comment: you're suggestions solved the problem. I'll copy my working code into an answer.